# remove button is not showing in kendo file upload

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I had use a kendo upload  but there is no remove button to delete the uploaded file.The code i used is below also the image is attached.[image: Kendo_File_Upload]

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                        .Name("files")
                        .Async(a => a
                            .Save("UploadAllDoc", "EmployeeDocuments")
                                            .Remove("UploadAllDoc", "EmployeeDocuments")
                            .AutoUpload(true)
                        )
                                                .Events(events => events.Success("onDocSuccess")
                                                                        .Upload("onImageUpload")
                                                                        .Complete("onDocComplete")
                                                        )
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution: controller action Method --> UploadAllDoc.

Should  return content('');

[reference](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/async)